# Vertical grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following 3 columns. I want to carve out results where **'AlphaCode'** matches and all the values in **'Group1'** have same values in **'Group2'**. For example for the following table, grouping of 1121TA and 1161TA should get carved out and 2807AHQ should be obtained in the output.

[image]

The output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is row 11, 12 since the linking in group1 does not exist in group2. For example for first group of Alphacode (1121TA) 340, 341 and 342 have same values in Group 2, so that should get carved out.

Comment: I keep reading this and think I understand what you want but then again I am not so sure. You might want to take a look here for some excellent advice on how to improve this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: So, the final result of what you seek is: both lines of 2807AHQ since all the others have no repeated groups?

Comment: Yes, @abr I am trying to get output only when the alphaCode matches but Group1 values does not have same values in Group2.

Comment: I guess the logic is this.  Collect all distinct group1 per alphacode and call it set1.  If for all set1 the value in group2 is the same, then I don't want to display this alphacode.  By the way, what are alphacode, group1 and group2 are? Are they company codes?

Comment: @SamitaPradhan check my answer below

Comment: @SamitaPradhan also, note that None of the records you've displayed have Group1 values in group2 values

Comment: That is why I have given heading as a 'Vertical comparison', this is not a typical horizontal comparison issue where Group1 values will be eqal to Group2. If you see closely there is a match in vertical groups with Group1 and Group2.

Comment: select * from t1 where Group1 in (select Group1 from t1 group by Group1 HAVING COUNT(Group1) <= 1)
and Group2 in (select Group2 from t1 group by Group2 HAVING COUNT(Group2) <= 1);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here you have one possible solution:

```
USE tempdb
GO
CREATE TABLE t
(
    AlphaCode varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Group1 int NOT NULL,
    Group2 int NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('1121TA', 342, 50285),
('1121TA', 340, 50285),
('1121TA', 341, 50285),
('1121TA', 341, 50345),
('1121TA', 342, 50345),
('1121TA', 340, 50345),
('1161TA', 355, 50347),
('1161TA', 354, 50347),
('1161TA', 354, 50458),
('1161TA', 355, 50458),
('2807AHQ', 77933, 50427),
('2807AHQ', 69939, 51897)
GO


WITH B AS
(
    SELECT 
        t.AlphaCode, t.Group1, t.Group2,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.AlphaCode, t.Group2) AS GroupCount
    FROM t
)
SELECT B.AlphaCode, B.Group1, B.Group2
FROM B
WHERE B.GroupCount = 1

GO
```

Another solution that works even on SQL Server 6.5:

```
SELECT t.AlphaCode, t.Group1, t.Group2
FROM
    t INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            t.AlphaCode, t.Group2, COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
        FROM 
            t
        GROUP BY
            t.AlphaCode, t.Group2
    ) gc ON t.AlphaCode = gc.AlphaCode AND t.Group2 = gc.Group2
WHERE
    gc.GroupCount = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

By 'carved out' I believe you mean, you want the records where Group1 isn't repeated.
Taking this into consideration you may want to:
Edit: After all the comments, I kinda give up but here's my last attempt:

"If you see closely there is a match in vertical groups with Group1 and Group2."

```
select * from t1 
      where Group1 in 
            (select Group1 from t1 
                    group by Group1 HAVING COUNT(Group1) <= 1)
      and Group2 in 
            (select Group2 from t1 
                    group by Group2 HAVING COUNT(Group2) <= 1);
```

"Group1 value must not be in Group2 value"

```
select * from t1 where Group1 not in (select distinct Group2 from t1)
```

"Select all the rows where Group1/Group2 is unique"

(You can change Group1 to Group2, depending on your needs)

```
select * from t1 group by Group1 HAVING COUNT(Group1) <= 1;
```

If you want the "AlphaCode Match", you kinda need to ask what you're really looking for, because that's a `where AlphaCode = "something"`

I've created a fiddle to be easier to reproduce what you look for. Feel free to use it to complete your post

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f75b5d/11

Comment: your first answer had no SYNTAX sense, this one doesnt solve the OP Problem and actually it makes no LOGICAL sense since it gives you all records

Comment: 1st, what I can tell of what op is asking is a group by. 2nd of, he's not being clear on what output should be presented, how about you try to help him instead?

Comment: if op question is not clear, then use comments to ask him make it more clear.

Comment: The above code is not working, since the aggregate function is not included in select or group by.

Comment: @SamitaPradhan Post a fiddle into your post, my fiddle is a representation of your screenshots and the query works. Also, not making much sense by saying 'Group1 value must not be in Group2' when none of the records you've displayed have a case where that happens.  That would be a simple where Group1 not in (Select distinct group 2 from table)

Comment: Like I explained in my comment before, this is not a horizontal comparison, so I am getting all the rows as an output on using `select * from t1 where Group1 not in (select distinct Group2 from t1)`.

Comment: @SamitaPradhan Check the updated answer. I've placed where group1 is unique in its column and group 2 unique in it's column

Comment: Thanks for your help @abr, Still I am getting partially correct output for the whole set of data. I will research more on this issue and update if I need help again.